# Wordpress Product Categories Widget - show more rows

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am having a problem with this widget. [Wordpress Product Categories Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33zN6.png) On the website, [vivahair.ro/shop](https://vivahair.ro/shop/) you can see it on top, called "Selecteaza o Cateorie". When it is collapsed, dropdowned, it only shows 5 rows.

Is it possible to display it like 90% of vizual height? Or at least 10-15 rows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `max-height: 200px;` to a larger value of this class

`.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options`.

It will display more rows.